# Bulk DB Operation Strategy

Tags: android, sql, sqlite, bulkinsert

I've got a SQLite DB running within an Android app that transfers user data in one month batches.

Upon first run of the app, with no data yet downloaded, storing is a trivial matter with INSERTS.

However, when the user re-downloads a months worth of data (to get any potential updates from the master DB (I want to push small, one record updates, but that's a 2.0 feature)) I need to find an efficient way to store the records.

Currently, I use brute force and simply DELETE all records for the month being refreshed, followed by INSERTS. I didn't want to have a whole bunch of logic and DB accesses, or store meta data, to keep track of which records are new and which are existing, and then perform INSERTS and UPDATES accordingly.

My boss said that DELETE can be an expensive operation, is this true ? Should I put in some logic to figure out what records should be updated and which should be inserted, rather than DELETING and then INSERTING ?  This strategy would also need to figure out which records were deleted on the master DB side as well (another reason I opted out).

If there is a completely better/efficient way to do this that I haven't mentioned by all means please let me know. Thanks.

Comment: Delete+Insert is two database operations as opposed to one with update. If there are indexes involved, the cost can be higher. The question is, how much data are you working with? I would do a volume test with delete+insert first. If performance is acceptable, you could argue that going for a more complex strategy isn't worth the effort...

Comment: Its about 1 MB, roughly, less for smaller municipalities, and potentially significantly more for the larger ones. We'll, since most of the operations will be updates, there is another reason to add the logic, though I'd really rather not, since time is a major factor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My boss said that DELETE can be an expensive operation, is this true ?

That depends on one's definition of "expensive". I am not aware that a `DELETE` is significantly more expensive than an `UPDATE` for the same affected records (in fact, it may be cheaper).

> Should I put in some logic to figure out what records should be updated and which should be inserted, rather than DELETING and then INSERTING ?

We have no good way of answering that question, because it is largely dependent upon your environment, such as your database schema.

Make sure that you are wrapping these operations in a transaction, as that has a major impact on the speed of bulk operations.

Beyond that, you would need to run some performance benchmarks of your own, to determine how much more expensive `DELETE`+`INSERT` is over `UPDATE`, and therefore whether it is worth the development headache or not to try to switch to an `UPDATE`-centric strategy.

Comment: I do use transactions in other places where I need exclusive write access (when the background process updates records queued up while there is no DB connection, and the user potentially has the record opened, among many other fun scenarios). This area I'm working on needs major optimizations, b/c currently, for each record and sub record, a separate DB operation is performed, including opening and closing a DB connection. It is just how it progressed, but man is it slow. Whatever route I choose, I will surely be doing it as a bulk operation (build one, or a few, bug command strings). Thnks

Comment: I thought SQLite implicitly wrapped all commands in a transaction? So, if I did execute a single, bulk (as in on massive string) command containing hundreds or thousands of inserts, wouldn't it already be in a transaction ? How do you define bulk, b/c I think my idea is different than yours ?

Comment: @SamusArin: "if I did execute a single, bulk (as in on massive string) command containing hundreds or thousands of inserts, wouldn't it already be in a transaction ?" -- I have never tried that. I would expect it to be "hundreds or thousands" of transactions. Not to mention it would be a tremendous waste of RAM to build a single SQL string representing "hundreds or thousands" of inserts. Please use `beginTransaction()` and kin to wrap individual `execSQL()` calls into a transaction.

Comment: Oh man if your telling me that alls I need to do is wrap everything in a transaction I'm going to be set! I'll give it a shot. Thanks a lot for clearing things up too.

Comment: It worked! I just shaved 1 minute down to 10 seconds!!! My repositories were already setup to perform transactions, I just wasn't using them in this case. Thanks so much, I'm so glad I got to leverage my existing code and not have to write a whole new data access layer that built a huge command string for nothing!